# Remounting root filesystem read only fails even though no files are opened for writing

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, mount

I am managing a couple of devices running Debian Buster. They all have separate partitions for /, /boot, and /var (all ext4), and Swap, such that I can keep / mounted read-only during normal operation. When upgrading the system, I remount / read-write, do the required changes (such as package upgrades) and then remount the filesystem read-only again.

Sometimes (e.g. when upgrading a daemon) the final remount fails, of course, since a now-deleted file is still opened by some process. In this case I simply restart the affected daemon and retry the remount.

However for a couple of weeks or so I have observed that the remount now fails even though there are no files pending for deletion left. Specifically, I tried these commands:

```bsh
$ sudo lsof / | grep DEL
$ sudo lsof / | awk '$4 ~ /[0-9].*[wu]/'
$ sudo fuser -vm / -wik
```

None of the commands showed any file pending for deletion/opened for writing and fuser did not kill anything. But still, remounting read-only fails:

```bsh
$ sudo mount -o remount,ro  /
mount: /: mount point is busy.
```

What am I missing? How can I investigate further what exactly prevents the remount?

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I kind of figured out what's going on: One process has a memory mapped file. However, I haven't found a way to tell whether a memory mapped file is actually mapped with write access. Can `lsof` tell me that?